# Getting UserID from the Session In Extjs in some other js files of same App

Tags: session, extjs

In other way I want to access

**(One functions Variable in another function in some other file of same application)**

I'm trying to retrieve the UserID i got it from the session in some other .js files of a same application, How will I be able to do it?
This is my 
**session.js**

```
function SessRequest() {

};

SessRequest.prototype.get = function (url, params, payload, session, cb, scope) {
    var data = {};

    if (payload) {
        data.payload = payload;
    }
    if (url.indexOf('?') > -1) {
        url = url + '&logonID=' + session.user.userID;
    } else {
        url = url + '?logonID=' + session.user.userID;
    }
    cb.call(scope, result.message, resp);
    });

    SessRequest.prototype.post = function (url, params, payload, session, cb, scope) {

    params.logonID = session.user.userID;
    rest.post(url, {data: params}).on('complete', function (data) {
        cb.call(scope, 0, data);
    });
};
```

Now This `session.user.userID`, I want this value to retrieve in a grid.js file of the same application, Can anyone help me in this ?
say me how to retrieve it and print it on console? If possible.

Please ask for any extra thing if My question is not clear?

thanks in advance

Comment: Is above function is getting called anytime? If yes just add the userid to your app name. Let's says my app name is myapp then do it like this myapp.userid = session.user.Userid. in grid directly acess it from myapp.userid

Comment: That userId is the is grabbed as the username when logging. the function is not called in the application anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a singleton class which holds the `userid` information.

```
Ext.define('APP.SessionInformation', {
    singleton: true,
    userid: null
});
```

When you retrived the information after successful login, you set it in the singleton.

```
APP.SessionInformation.userid = session.user.userID;
```

Now you are able to access it everywhere in you application by `APP.SessionInformation.userid`.